# Stop closing the dropdown menu on Hover

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu that shows on hover. The menu becomes hidden again after I mouse away from it and I can't click on any of submenus.

```
$('.toggle-menu').on('hover',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().siblings().children('.toggle-menu').removeClass('show').next().slideUp();
        $(this).toggleClass('show').next().slideToggle();
        e.stopPropagation();
});
```

How can I stop closing the dropdown menu if the mouse is hover the dropdown container?

[**My jsFiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/3uLxb/1/)

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mouseover solution has a slight problem if you hit the menu too quick while it is sliding.

Use the li as a parent:

```
$('.toggle-menu-parent').on('hover', function(e){    
        e.preventDefault();

        $(this).siblings().children('.toggle-menu').removeClass('active').next().slideUp();

        $(this).find('.toggle-menu').toggleClass('active').next().slideToggle();

    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3uLxb/16/

Comment: That's, like, my answer :D

Comment: Sorry Ivan just saw it we did it very simular but you was first!

Comment: I'm just kidding :D No hard feelings :)

Answer (score 4):

use mouseover instead of hover

change

```
$('.toggle-menu').on('hover',function(e){
```

to

```
$('.toggle-menu').on('mouseover',function(e){
```

Comment: I had the same idea. Maybe need a 'click' to close or hide?

Answer (score 3):

js

```
$('.toggle').on('hover',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).siblings().children('.toggle-menu').removeClass('active').next().slideUp();
        $(this).find('.toggle-menu').toggleClass('active').next().slideToggle();
        e.stopPropagation();
});
```

html

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="toggle">
        <a href="#" class="toggle-menu"><span></span>MENU 1</a>
        <ul class="menu1">
            <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="toggle">
        <a href="#" class="toggle-menu"><span></span>MENU 2</a>
        <ul class="menu2">
            <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3uLxb/15/

Answer (score 1):

use **mouseover and mouseout**  event  to handle this.

```
$('.toggle-menu').on('mouseover',function(e){...
```

check this
http://jsfiddle.net/nkNUz/
     use mouseout event to hide according to your logic

Answer (score 1):

Actually, what you should do is encapsulate your `<li>`s in divs with `overflow:hidden` and your `height` set that only the "Menu" item showing.

On `hover` you should `animate` your `height` downward to show all `<li>`s.  You won't need to `mouseover` or `mouseout` separately if you are selecting the `<div>` as your jQuery element.